# RSpec not printing failure reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I managed to mess up my gemsets by mixing rvm and sudo. Ended up having to uninstall ruby, rvm and start from scratch. Now I've got everything up and running, except my RSpec isn't behaving as it should be. All it displays is:

> bundle exec rspec spec/
>       ..................................................................F.

In the past it would display a detailed failure report showing which test failed, and why, like:

```
1)
'User should be in any roles assigned to it' FAILED
expected in_role?("assigned role") to return true, got nil
./user_spec.rb:7:


Finished in 0.0172110000000001 seconds



1 example, 1 failure
```

I've tried playing with the various formatter options. The 'd' option gives me the most verbose results, but these are too verbose as every single test that succeeds is also printed in full on a new line, which quickly starts turning the report into pages.

What can I change to make RSpec work like before?

Answer (score 1):

You need ask to rspec say the complete backtrace. The option is `--backtrace` or `-b`

You can define it in your `.rspec` file in your directory or in your `rspec` command line.

Comment: Already tried it. That didn't work either:  

bundle exec rspec --backtrace spec/

..................................................................F.